# case statement alternatives in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, switch-statement

I have a script that is dependent on the hostname. If the hostname is X, then use Y as the variable for that host is the kind of requirement.

The mapping is in a file. There are about 50 mappings. I was able to work it out with a case statement, but looking for easier alternatives to read the mapping from a file rather than me writing a case statement for all 50 servers.

Example:

Mappings file is `file.txt`.

```
Apple   Fruit
chair   furniture
man     human
pizza   food
```

My logic that is working:

```
hostname=uname -n
case $hostname in
    chair )
        Qmgr=furniture
        rest of my code here
        ;;
    Apple )
        Qmgr=fruit
        rest of my code here
        ;;
    man )
        Qmgr=Human
        rest of my code here
        ;;
    pizza )
        Qmgr=Food
        rest of my code here
        ;;
    * )
        not recognized serer from the mappings file.txt
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You can read the contents of `file.txt` into an associative array, but it's not clear what your `case` statement is doing. The first two cases make sense (set `Qmgr` to the second column from the file if the host name matches the first column), but the second two do not.

Comment: Why is `man=human` a case, instead of setting `Qmgr=human` when `$hostname` matches `man`? You can read `file.txt` into an associative array so that you could write something like `Qmgr=${managers[$(uname -n)]}`, but that won't address `rest of my code`.

Comment: My bad on last 2 case statements. I corrected them.

Comment: rest of the code is simple build stuff(like building directories based on the variable Qmgr)

Comment: If "rest of my code here" is the same for each case, you can easily construct the case statement automatically.  If it is different (and not easily automatbale), you're going to have to hand write some code.

Comment: Note that the similar code should be factored out of the case statement and not automatically generated as boilerplate.  That is the way to madness.

Comment: understand. i can take the rest of the code out of it.

Comment: Looks like you just need something like `Qmgr=$(awk '$1==host{print $2}' host=$(hostname) config-file)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the data into an associative array.

```
declare -A managers
while read -r host mgr; do
    managers[$host]=$mgr
done < file.txt

hostname=$(uname -n)
qmgr=${managers[$hostname]}

if [[ -z $qmgr ]]; then
    printf 'Unrecognized server %s\n' "$hostname"
fi
```

Comment: What is $mgr doing here.

Comment: `read` can split each line of the file as it reads it. So for the first line, `host` is `Apple` and `mgr` is `Fruit`, etc.

Comment: thank you that worked. One cavet is, I am running this script remotely. that is script would be local on a central server and will execute the logic on target server. trying to tweak to work with remote ssh.